# How do I check if order item has meta field 'Backordered'?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Please advise how to check if 'Backordered' meta field exists for some item in new Woocommerce order. I'm trying to add a note for customer on new order but can't find out why my function doesn't work:

```
function tt_backorder_warning_note ( $order_id ) { 

    $tt_order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $tt_items = $tt_order->get_items();
    $tt_backorder = FALSE;
    $tt_backordered_note = 'Some text to warn customer that they will wait longer';

    foreach ($tt_items as $tt_item) {
        if ($tt_item['Предзаказано']) { // Предзаказано = Backordered
            $tt_backorder = TRUE;
            break;
        }
    }

    if($tt_backorder) {
        $tt_order->add_order_note( $tt_backordered_note, $is_customer_note = 1 );
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'tt_backorder_warning_note' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the meta on the product:

```
function tt_backorder_warning_note ( $order_id ) { 

    $tt_order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $tt_items = $tt_order->get_items();
    $tt_backorder = FALSE;
    $tt_backordered_note = 'Some text to warn customer that they will wait longer';

    foreach ($tt_items as $tt_item) {

        if ($tt_item->is_on_backorder()) {
            $tt_backorder = TRUE;
            break;
        }
    }

    if($tt_backorder) {
        $tt_order->add_order_note( $tt_backordered_note);
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'tt_backorder_warning_note' );
```

Comment: thanks for help, but it still doesn't add note. Maybe thereš another way to check if some product was backordered?

Comment: Actually, I looked and there is a function in WC_product called `is_on_backorder()`. Editing my answer to use that.

Comment: I just made it mathematically, it did the trick:
```
    foreach ($tt_order->get_items() as $item_id => $item_data) {

        $product = $item_data->get_product();
        $item_quantity = $item_data->get_quantity(); 
        $current_stock = $product->get_stock_quantity();
        $out_of_stock = $current_stock - $item_quantity;

        if ( $out_of_stock < 0 && $product->backorders_allowed() ) {
            $tt_backorder = TRUE;
        }
    }```